# Is this space a close subspace of $H^1(‎\Omega‎)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces

I define the following space

$$H(‎\Omega‎) = \{ u\in H^1(‎\Omega‎)\: \: \text{such that}\: \: ‎\Delta u‎ ‎=0 ‎\:\: \text{‎in} ‎\:\: ‎‎\Omega‎‎ \},$$
where $H^1(‎\Omega‎)$ is a Hilbert space, and $\Omega$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
How can I show that it is a close subspace of $H^1(‎\Omega‎)$?

Comment: How one can "show that it is a close[d] subspace" will depend on the background you bring to the study of this Sobolev space.  Please add context to your Question [as recommended here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).  In particular the meaning of $\Delta u‎ ‎=0$ in your space is central to proving it describes a closed subspace relative to the topology of the vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean $ \Delta u = 0$ in the sense that $$ \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla \varphi \, dx =0 $$ for all $\varphi \in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$.

Suppose that $\{ u_k \} \subset H(\Omega)$ converges to $u$ in $H^1(\Omega)$. To show $H(\Omega)$ is closed we need to prove $u \in H(\Omega)$. Indeed, for each $\varphi \in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$, $$\bigg \vert \int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot\nabla\varphi \, dx \bigg \vert =\bigg \vert \int_\Omega \nabla (u-u_k) \cdot\nabla \varphi \, dx \bigg \vert \leqslant C \| u_k -u \|_{H^1(\Omega)} \to 0 $$ as $k \to \infty$. Hence, $$\int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot\nabla\varphi \, dx=0. $$ Thus, $u \in H(\Omega)$.

Technically, you should also check that $H(\Omega)$ is a subspace of $H^1(\Omega)$ but this follows directly from linearity of $\Delta$ so I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Yes, I know the last (subspace) part. I failed to show that it is close. I really appreciate you.